# how to extend autocomplete popup width when using md-contact-chips?

Tags: autocomplete, width

I'm using md-contact-chips to get employees' photo, name and emails. but the pop up window which is from autocomplete component is to narrow. How to extend the width or overwrite the css? 
I've got info from github, one way is to use md-autocomplete-snap=width to fix it. But I don't know how to use it together with md-contact-chips.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKlsI.jpg)

```
 <md-content class="md-padding autocomplete" layout="column">

                    <br>
                    <h2 class="md-title">Searching asynchronously.</h2>
                    <md-contact-chips
                            ng-model="asyncContacts"
                            md-autocomplete-snap="width"
                            md-contacts="delayedQuerySearch($query)"
                            md-contact-name="profile_name"
                            md-contact-image="profile_imageURL"
                            md-contact-email="profile_intranetID"
                            md-require-match="true"
                            md-highlight-flags="i"
                            filter-selected="filterSelected"
                            placeholder="To">
                    </md-contact-chips>
                </md-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option I found was to add to the following css class:

```
.md-chips .md-chip-input-container {
    width: 100%;
}
```